# Unable to get road length using osmpy

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I'm really struggling to get road lengths for my polygon. I'm new to python and QGIS and my script, while successful, doesn't return anything.

I've installed [osmpy](https://github.com/JoaoCarabetta/osmpy) and in the python console within QGIS I'm executing the below, which appears to run successfully:

```
import osmpy
from shapely import wkt
boundary = wkt.loads('POLYGON((-46.63 -23.54,-46.6 -23.54,-46.62 -23.55,-46.63 -23.55,-46.63 -23.54))')
osmpy.get('RoadLength', boundary)
```

The result being:

```
exec(Path('C:/Users/User 1/RoadLength.py').read_text())
```

But I don't get any other output? The example [here](https://github.com/JoaoCarabetta/osmpy), shows other output, but I'm not sure where that comes from?

I tried executing the script but the result of that is just:

```
exec(Path('C:/Users/User 1/RoadLength.py').read_text())
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell python what to do with the results of the `osmpy.get` call.

If you change your last line to

```
print(osmpy.get('RoadLength', boundary))
```

you will get a result printed. The OSM python console does not by default print the results of statetements run from the editor.